# Require syntax for rbenv::compile in puppet

Tags: puppet

I have the following code:

```
  rbenv::compile { "1.9.3-p327":
    user => "vagrant",
    home => "/home/vagrant",
  }

  exec {"rbenv-global-1.9.3-p327":
    command => "rbenv global 1.9.3-p327",
    path => "/home/vagrant/.rbenv/bin",
  }
```

I would like to add a require to "rbenv-global-1.9.3-p327" because it should be executed after rbenv::compile but I do not know the right syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't know the right syntax, why don't you look it up? The Puppet documentation is excellent, especially the "Learning Puppet" sections. You want the `require` keyword, and you want to read *at least* all of http://docs.puppetlabs.com/learning/index.html.

This should do it:

```
rbenv::compile { "1.9.3-p327":
  user => "vagrant",
  home => "/home/vagrant",
}

exec {"rbenv-global-1.9.3-p327":
  command => "rbenv global 1.9.3-p327",
  path    => "/home/vagrant/.rbenv/bin",
  require => Rbenv::Compile['1.9.3-p327']
}
```

Alternatively you can use chaining arrows to create the relationship explicitly:

```
rbenv::compile { "1.9.3-p327":
  user => "vagrant",
  home => "/home/vagrant",
}

exec {"rbenv-global-1.9.3-p327":
  command => "rbenv global 1.9.3-p327",
  path    => "/home/vagrant/.rbenv/bin",
}

Rbenv::Compile['1.9.3-p327'] ->
Exec['rbenv-global-1.9.3-p327']
```